# Assign names to dataframes within a list based on combn

Tags: r, list, plyr, combn

I have created a list of dataframes using alply (~500), in the manner;

```
prevalence <- alply(combos, 2, prevalence.func)
```

I'd like to assign new names to each data.frame based on the same combos, replacing the default numeric names 1,2,3...500.

Reproducible example created using:

```
simple_list = replicate(n = 10,
                 expr = {data.frame(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))},
                 simplify = F)

combos <-combn(1:5, 2)
```

So that the names of each dataframe...

```
simple_list$1 becomes simple_list$1-2
simple_list$10 becomes simple_list$4-5
```

...which tells me over which interval each data.frame was computed across in the original function.

I tried using lapply with;

```
someFunction <-function (x){

  names(simple_list)<-paste(combos[x,x[1]],combos[x,x[2]],sep="-")

 }

lapply(simple_list,someFunction)
```

But I recieve there error:

```
Error in combos[x, x[1]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Something is obviously not right with my assignment function. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `combn` has a `FUN` argument, so it can be

```
 names(simple_list) <- combn(5,2, FUN= paste, collapse='-')
 names(simple_list)
 #[1] "1-2" "1-3" "1-4" "1-5" "2-3" "2-4" "2-5" "3-4" "3-5" "4-5"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
names(simple_list)<-lapply(combn(5,2,simplify=FALSE),function(x) paste(x,collapse="-"))
#names(simple_list)
#[1] "1-2" "1-3" "1-4" "1-5" "2-3" "2-4" "2-5" "3-4" "3-5" "4-5"
```